# Calling a procedure in Delphi

Tags: delphi, object, procedure

I have a procedure with `Sender: TObject` paramater

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
```

How can I call this procedure again?

This version does not work:

```
TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to call it with object instance. so if you need to call it from your form code, you have to use `self.FormCreate(self)` or just `FromCreate(self)`, and if you dont' need sender - `FormCreate(nil)`. btw it is not good idea to call `FormCreate` again.

Comment: The Sender is mostly not used by beginners and simple software. Sender is the ability to know who send the call, and if it netters, choose a way of action, or even to make a procedure call like sender.proc, in the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you wish to call the procedure `FormCreate` of an instance of a `TForm1`.

You can do `FormCreate(Self)` or `FormCreate(nil)` (or you can pass any `TObject` instance as the parameter) if you are inside the `TForm1` class. Otherwise, you have to write `Form1.FormCreate(Self)` or `Form1.FormCreate(nil)` or similarly, where `Form1` is the appropriate *instance* of the `TForm1`.

At any rate, it is not particularly 'elegant' to call the `FormCreate` procedure at later times. Indeed, the name clearly suggests that the procedure is called when the form is created.

If a particular piece of logic of your `FormCreate` method is needed at other stages and you simply do not want to duplicate code, you should probably implement that piece in the form of a separate method (procedure or function) and call it in `FormCreate` as well as in other parts of your program, as necessary.

But then, you might be better off moving that part of your business logic from `FormCreate` at all. What we typically do in `FormCreate` is create/initialise objects that are later uninitialised/destroyed in `FormDestroy` (if needed). So, think carefully *what* you are doing in `FormCreate`, maybe there's a better, logically more appropriate place for some or all of the actions you've implemented in this method.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
Please advise me a better way to execute code from TForm1.FormCreate (Sender: TObject); elsewhere. Of course, not copying it.

Comment: Put the code you wish to reuse in a separate function, and call that function from your OnCreate _and_ from the other areas where you need to call it, perhaps?

Comment: @Liviu: Refactor. Apparently some part of your `FormCreate` makes sense to execute several times. Put that part in its own procedure, with a suitable name, such as `LoadListOfFiles` (or whatever makes sense in your application -- most likely not that name!). Then call `LoadListOfFiles` in your `FormCreate`, and at any other time you wish. This way you can also do stuff in `FormCreate` that you should indeed only do when the form is actually created.

Comment: I was bold enough to add some suggestions to your otherwise correct answer. Please feel free to roll it back or edit it as much as you wish if you think my additions undermine your main idea. (Note: I could see none of the comments at the time of editing.)

Comment: I tried so,but it doesn't work.
`TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    procedure ajax(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure ajax(Sender:TObject);
begin

end;`

Comment: @LiviuSolcovenco: You seem to be confusing very different things: *declaration/definition* of a method (procedure or function) and *calling* of a method. When you declare (or should I say, define) a method in the `implementation` section, you specify its name together with the name of the *class* it belongs to. In your case, the method header in `implementation` should read: `procedure TForm1.ajax(Sender: TObject);`. …

Comment: @LiviuSolcovenco: But when you *call* this method, you might not need the prefix and you reference it simply by the name `ajax`: `…; ajax(whatever); …`. You can do so from within a method of *the same class*. But when you call `ajax` in a method of a different class, specify the appropriate *instance* name as a prefix: `…; Form1.ajax(whatever); …`.

Comment: The problem is that you barrely know the language. You should study a bit the procedural types in Delphi, *procedures*, *functions*, *overloading*, *prototypes*, parmeter types *var,const,in,out,untyped*, etc...The answer is actually pretty bad because you've probably learnt nothing from it.

Comment: @az01: Very true. The OP really should learn the basics of OOP in Delphi (e.g., the difference between a class and an instance). Still, it is not always the case that you have time/energy enough to write an entire tutorial when you find a question in which the OP lacks fundamental knowledge in the subject. My answer is entirely correct, though, from a technical point of view...